# Algorithm to convert string to GUID

Tags: c++, algorithm, guid

I am trying to create a function that takes an arbitrary string as input and creates a GUID based on that string. The GUID's format should be ideally the `GUID` struct from `objbase.h`, but it's not that important. What is important is that the function is deterministic but always (or close enough to always) creates a different GUID for different strings.

What kind of algorithm could I use to do that? I've thought about bit operations on the contents of the string but I would appreciate some direction.

Comment: Why would you want a GUID as result, instead of a hash function's output which likely has a larger range and is less regular?

Comment: You want to use string as a SEED ? You want different output for different strings and you want different output for even if strings are same?

Comment: Guid have a certain purpose and meaning. I agree with Delian, use a hash or like Thb, use md5

Answer (score 2):

What about computing an MD5 hash of the string and treating it as if it were a GUID?  GUIDs and MD5 hashes are both 128-bit values.

Answer (score 1):

You can hash the string and then use the first 16 bytes of the hash to create a GUID (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the specifications for UUID version 3 and 5:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_3_.28MD5_hash.29
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_5_.28SHA-1_hash.29

In essence, you compute MD5 (or SHA-1) of your string and store the results verbatim in a 128-bit UUID. For SHA-1, you need to truncate the result, as SHA-1 returns 160-bits.